# Twilio SendGrid - Get unsubscribe list on v3 api

Tags: twilio, sendgrid-api-v3

I am working with Twilio SendGrid v3 api using C#.

I have a custome page that shows emails that were sent out via SendGrid. On that page, I would like to show one of **email recipient has been unsubscribed** as a badge.

After spend hours and the closest resource can achieve v2 endpoint and resource is below link.

https://docs.sendgrid.com/v2-api/unsubscribes#maincontent

**Can I get unsubscribe list via v3 endpoint? or alternativly can I call v2 endpoint through v3 library?**

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Self resolved, they re-consepted unsubscribe to be a part of **suppression**.

There is documentation in Supression Management menus.

https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/suppressions-global-suppressions/add-recipient-addresses-to-the-global-suppression-group

Here is just a example code to get unsubscribed list(C#).

```
string apiKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SENDGRID_API_KEY");
var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);


var response = await client.RequestAsync(
    method: SendGridClient.Method.GET,
    urlPath: "suppression/unsubscribes"
);
```

Hope this page helps others.